# Need help/stuck on overload generic method

Tags: java

I need to overload generic method printArray of GenericMethodtest so that

> it takes two additional integer arguments, `lowsubscript` and `highsubscript`. A call to this method prints only the designated portion of the array. Validate `lowsubscript` and `highsubscript`. if either is out of range, the overloaded `printarray` method should throw an `invalidsubscriptexception`; otherwise, `printArray` should return the number of elements printed.
>
> Then modify main to exercise both verisons of `printArray` on arrays `integerArray`, `doubleArray` and `characterArray`. Test all capabilities of both versions of `printArray`.

This is what I have so far i'm stuck and don't know where to begin.

```
public class GenericMethodTest   
{     
  public static void main(String[] args)   
  {        
     // create arrays of Integer, Double and Character  
     Integer[] integerArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};   
     Double[] doubleArray = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7};   
     Character[] characterArray = {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'}   
  
   
     System.out.printf("%nArray integerArray contains:%n");
     printArray(integerArray); // pass an Integer array 
     System.out.printf("%nArray doubleArray contains:%n");
     printArray(doubleArray); // pass a Double array
     System.out.printf("%nArray characterArray contains:%n");
     printArray(characterArray); // pass a Character array
   }    

   // generic method printArray       
   public static <T> void printArray(T[] inputArray)      
   {
     // display array elements  
     for (T element : inputArray)   
       System.out.printf("%s ", element);

     System.out.println();
   }
} // end class GenericMethodTest
```

Comment: Start by defining a new `printArray` method that takes additional parameters. At this point, all you have done is an assignment dump without any effort. Please see [What can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), point 3.

Comment: what is your problem? how to return count?

Comment: There is no need to use generics here, because arrays are covariant. Just declare `Object[] inputArray`. Or, to put this another way, the fact the method is generic is entirely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Do you want to override a **static** method?

Answer (score -1):

public class Print {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Double[] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7 };
    Character[] charArray = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };
    
    System.out.println( "Array integerArray contains:" );
    printArray( intArray ); 
    printArray( intArray , 0, 3); //1 2 3 4
    System.out.println( "\nArray doubleArray contains:" );
    printArray( doubleArray ); 
    printArray( doubleArray , 2, 4); //3.3 4.4 5.5 
    System.out.println( "\nArray characterArray contains:" );
    printArray( charArray );
    printArray( charArray , 3, 8); //exception
    
}

private static <T> void printArray(T[] arr) {
    printArray(arr, 0, arr.length-1);

}

private static <T> void printArray(T[] arr, int low, int high) {
    if(low<0 || high>arr.length-1) {
        throw new InvalidSubscriptException("Illegal lowSubscribt or highSubscribt");
    }
    for(int i=low; i<high+1; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%s ", arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: public class InvalidSubscriptException extends RuntimeException {
 
public InvalidSubscriptException() {
  this("InvalidSubscribtException");
 }
 
 public InvalidSubscriptException(String s) {
  super(s);
 }
}

Comment: Can you please add a few words explaining your code?